# Jmeter for java applets?

Tags: java, applet, jmeter

I want to record a script for java applet here ,what I am trying to record
launch java applet from web browser 
login to applet and answer questions on applet.
But I am only able to record when i click web browser and it launches applet
I am not able to record anything on applet 
I also tried by setting java proxy and HTTP sampler settings to java ,but still cannot record anything.
Can anyone please help me to record with java applet ?

Answer (score 0):

Technically JMeter does not record Java Applet's behavoiur and only records web requests and responses to the server. But if you are persist on modeling what the web page is doing with applet you should do something like this:

- Record all the requests
- Copy the java applet's jarfile into the `lib` folder of Jmeter.
- Then use a JSR233Sampler with Groovy as language wherever you want to use applet's method
- Use applet's full class path(packages from the start) to instanciate the main applet's class and then you can call whatever method inside that class.